# Convert an Excel formula to an Access query

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula

Is there a way to convert the below Excel formula to a query/criterion in Access?

```
L2 = Date
J2 = Another Date
Z1 = Todays Date
```

I think it is calculating the number of days in between two dates but not sure how to do this in an Access query.

```
IF((AND((L2<1),(J2>1))),(NETWORKDAYS(J2,$Z$1)-1),0)
```

Comment: Sample data? Access/Excel version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a reference to Excel.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    MsgBox GetNetWorkDays(#1/29/2017#, #2/8/2017#)
End Sub

Function GetNetWorkDays(startDate As Date, endDate As Date) As Integer
GetNetWorkDays = WorksheetFunction.NETWORKDAYS(startDate, endDate)
End Function
```

Put the button on a Form and click the button!

Answer (score 1):

As you may by now have gathered, the question does not really make sense. `NETWORKDAYS` does indeed calculate the number of “whole working days excluding weekends and any dates identified in holidays” between two dates (here whatever date is in `J2` and whatever is ‘Today’/`Z1`) and `IF` makes that calculation contingent upon the result of the `AND` function being TRUE. The `AND` function results in TRUE provided both the ‘date’ in `L2` is before 1/1/1900 and the date in `J2` is after 1/1/1900 (because to Excel 1/1/1900 is Day `1` where dates are concerned [unless one opts for the 1904 date system]).

But Excel does not recognise a date before Day 1, whether a negative number or a decimal number. For example Day 1.5 is noon on 1/1/1900 whereas in the same format Day 0.5 shows as 0/1/1900.

So in essence, `L2` is not a date of any real use to the formula, hence I believe why no answer yet to your question. But this is too long to fit in a comment hence my answer: “No.”!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate number of days between days than you can use below built in function "DateDiff" which will solve it out. Datediff("D",,)
Ex. Datediff("D",L2,Z1)